# Can't resolve 'react/jsx-dev-runtime' After updating React 16.13.1 -> 17.0.2

Tags: reactjs, webpack, next.js, babeljs, jsx

So I need to update react, react-dom in order to update nextjs version to 11. React docs says that the new jsx transform approach is backwards compatible, though I met such problem after updating to react 17.0.2. Any file using jsx fails to compile with **Can't resolve 'react/jsx-dev-runtime'**, no matter if I leave the **import React from 'react'**, or remove it as intended after updating to react ^17.

I tried updating *@babel/preset-react*, using latest *@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx*, same problem. The only thing I've found in a similar question topic here is adding /** @jsxRuntime classic */ to the top of the file, which obviously doesnt solve the problem for the whole application (perhaps there might be a way to make such directive global but even then - I would like to be able to use the new and more optimised jsx compiling)

Haven't been able to google exactly my case and any existing suggestions for similar cases didn't help.

To summarise - I need to either make my app work without importing react itself (**https://reactjs.org/blog/2020/09/22/introducing-the-new-jsx-transform.html**) or at least to be able to use the old way of jsx compiling with this new react version.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Do you have a link to the repository?
It is difficult to say here without checking your configuration files